# Solving PDE with change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble with solving a PDE using change of variables. I have the PDE

$$
u_t - ku_{xx} + au_x = 0, \quad x \in \mathbb{R},\, 0<t<T
$$

And if I let $v(x,t) = u(x+at,t)$, by the chain rule I have

$$
\begin{align}
v_t(x,t) &= au_x(x+at,t) + u_t(x+at,t) \\
v_x(x,t) &= u_x(x+at,t) \\
v_{xx}(x,t) &= u_{xx}(x+at,t)
\end{align}
$$

Now, I want to substitute these back into the PDE, but I don't see how it can be done, because the arguments are $x+at$ and $t$, rather than $x$ and $t$. Can someone tell me why that doesn't matter?

Comment: Aren't your variables still $x$ and $t$ though? I'm assuming $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes. And I suppose the transformations don't affect the domain of x or t. So I'm alright to sub straight back in (thus removing the $au_x$ term)?

Comment: Think about it like using a substitution in an indefinite integral. Once you have solved the equation in $v$, you are going to "unravel" the result in terms of $u$. Also, your notation is slightly confusing, as your original equation is in $u$, I would have thought it made more sense to set $u(x, t) = v(x + at, t)$, though I don't suppose it matters.

Comment: If I do it the other way round as you suggest, I'd need to use $x - at$ rather than $x + at$. I end up with the equation $v_t(x-at,t) - kv_{xx}(x-at,t) = 0$, which I suppose works just as well.